# Google App Engine - Task Queue Names and Transactions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

In the Google App Engine documentation it says below (see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html#Tasks_Within_Transactions)).

> Transactional tasks must not have
>   user-specified names.

Are tasks within transactions automatically assigned names or is there some other reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that task names are themselves transactional, and it's not possible to combine the two atomic operations (the datastore transaction and obtaining the task name) into a single atomic transaction.